# "This localhost page can’t be found" when add scaffolding identity in my project using asp.net core 7.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

When I add scaffolding identity into my project, the page return "This localhost page can’t be found". This is my dbContext class and my program.cs [The error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJAfn.png)
[DbContext Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53zmC.png)
[Program.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TEsL.jpg)

I try to find issue on google but all of them does not work. If I delete Identity folder, the page work again

Comment: Your default route is in customer area? In general identity will not change your default route.

Comment: Yes sir, my default route still in customer area

Comment: Sry, From your question i don't find any error, Maybe you can rebuild your project and try again.